# Edit a file that is exclusively checked out by another user in visual source safe(VSS)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-config, visual-sourcesafe, vssettings

I just want to edit a web config file in a source code through vss. But I am getting an error

> file is exclusively checked out by another user

I want to edit that file (no need to check in/no need to update my changes). How can do this..?

**Note** : I don't have administrator privilege

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When someone loading some project form VSS, all its files are in read-only mode. Check in resource control the file properties and switch of read-only mode. I hope this help.

Comment: :Thanks , need to untick readonly check box from properties